# How can I scale a pyplot colorbar so that contrast is seen in my scatter points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm making a scatter plot with `x` and `y` values, and a `z` array that I'm using to define point color as so:

`plt.scatter(x, y, c = z)`

However, `max(z) ~ 110`, but `mean(z) ~ 20`. So since most `z` values are around or below, but the max is around 100, most of the points look dark blue and its hard to tell a difference.

I tried to use a log colorbar, but since my `z` range is almost exactly from 10-100, it barely helps:

[image: color coded]

Is there a way to use a normal color scale up to a certain value? Like have the color bar go from Blue - Red from `10 - 40`, and then have everything above that just be red?

Comment: is there a `clim` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c = z, vmin=10, vmax=40)
```

Comment: This kind of works. It makes points with `z=40` deep red but it doesn;t display values greater than 40 on the color bar. I would like it to still display the whole range, but have the red extend from ~40 to the max. Ideally I would just have some color  bar scale that changes rapidly at first, and more slowly for higher `z`. Obviously a log scale would usually be the way to go, but having a range from ~10-~100 already makes it have little effect. Are there any alternatives or manipulations I can do to the log scale?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `extend` argument on the matplotlib colorbar as

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c = z, vmin=10, vmax=40)
plt.colorbar(extend="max")
```

For detailed examples, check [this link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html) out.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose this is good enough. I ended up using a log scale from 10-40, then using this `extend` arg. To do this, rather than passing `vmin` and `vmax` directly, I had to create an object like so: `matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=10, vmax=40)`, and pass this as the `norm` arg to `scatter`